# Alternative to eval() function due to minification

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I would like to create an object this way:

```
var new_obj = {},
    array_path = '',
    the_value = 3;

array_path = '[\''fruits'\'][\''banana'\'][\''value'\']'; // unknown on runtime
eval('new_obj' + array_path + ' = ' + the_value + ';');
```

Unfortunately after minification the 'new_obj' parameter won't match the new_obj variable. I can't figure out another way to do what I want, because the array_path structure is unknown to me on runtime. Any ideas how I can avoid the eval() function?

Comment: you can use constants as well as variables as array indexes, so just removing the eval and using `new_obj[var1][var2][var3]=the_value;` should work... what does the "unknown on runtime" comment mean, though?

Comment: If you're building the `array_path` string at runtime, you can just as well access the object through array notation. `eval()` is redundant in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertand your question correctly this might be what you are looking for:

```
var set_value = function(obj, path, value) {
    var limit = path.length;
    // You might want to check if limit is 0 here.
    for (var i = 0; i < limit-1; i++) {
        var key = path[i];
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Depending on your case you might throw an error
            // here or do something else
            obj[key] = {};
        }
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    obj[path[limit-1]] = value;
};
```

And usage:

```
var new_obj = {},
    array_path = ['foo', 'bar', 'test'],
    the_value = 3;

set_value(new_obj, array_path, the_value);
```

So all you have to do is convert `array_path` to a format as above. If you receive it as a string then some regular expressions might be helpful. Although if you have control over the source then just make sure that it is a JSON array.

BTW: Do not use hackish (or any) evals as you did above. Minification is the least of your problems. If you have no control over the source (and it is a good practice to always assume that you don't) then you have a huge security issue at the moment. Someone can inject harmful JavaScript with ease into your code.