# Issue with eval function using webpack (minification)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Im building a javascript library for my personal use that uses `eval` to evaluate a math equation from a json file. Im using nodejs to build all these and compiling using webpack to generate an index.js file which I then use in a web browser.

Im my json file I have multiple analyses definitions with their corresponding equations and point values.

```
{ "analysis_name": "analysis1", "points": { "A": (1,2), "B": (5,6) }, "equations": ["intersect(A,B)","distance(A,B)"] }
```

I want to be able to use `eval` to 1) generate variables A, B and then compute the corresponding equations from the array.

I wrote a function `run_analysis` to process this:

```
import {intersect, distance} from './utils'

function run_analysis(json_data) {
  const points = json_data['points'];
  const equations = json_data['equations'];
  // 1) Generate a variable for each point (A, B, etc)
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(points)) {
    eval(`var ${key} = [${value}];`);
  }
  // break1: console.log(A)
  // 2) Perform computation and generate output
  let results = []
  for (const equation of equations ) {
    results.push({
      'equation': equation ,
      'result': eval(equation)
    })
  }
  return results
}
```

The problem is that when minification occurs, on `break1`, the first eval that generates the variables names throws that `A` doesnt exists and the `eval` at 2) that computes the equations, says that neither `intersect` nor `distance` functions exists even though they are being imported.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having issues with the minification process or webpack itself?

Transpiled code

```
    (function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    else {
        var a = factory();
        for(var i in a) (typeof exports === 'object' ? exports : root)[i] = a[i];
    }
})(global, function() {
return /******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ 194:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "R": () => (/* binding */ analysis)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _config_analyses_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(34);



function analysis() {
  const data = _config_analyses_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__;

  // Define methods
  const instance = {
    available_analyses: function() {
      return Object.keys(data);
    },

    run_analysis: function(name, points) {
      const analysis = data[name]
      // Get analysis data
      const equations = analysis['equations']
      // Generate a variable for each point
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(points)) {
        eval(`var ${key} = [${value}];`);
      }
      // Perform computation and generate output
      let results = []
      for (const equation of equations) {
        results.push({
          'name': equation['formula'],
          'value': eval(equation['formula'])
        })
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  // Return instance
  return instance;
}


/***/ }),

/***/ 181:
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

// ESM COMPAT FLAG
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);

// EXPORTS
__webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
  "Analysis": () => (/* reexport */ analysis/* analysis */.R),
  "default": () => (/* binding */ index),
  "points": () => (/* reexport */ landmarks_namespaceObject)
});

// EXTERNAL MODULE: ./analysis/analysis.js
var analysis = __webpack_require__(194);
;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ../test/landmarks.json
const landmarks_namespaceObject = JSON.parse('{"A":[1224,880],"B":[1037,1744],"C":[1610,761]}');
;// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./index.js



/* harmony default export */ const index = (analysis/* analysis */.R);






/***/ }),

/***/ 34:
/***/ ((module) => {

module.exports = JSON.parse('{"analysis1":{"analysis_name":"analysis1","equations":[{"formula":"angle(A,B,C)"},{"formula":"dist(A,B)"}]}}');

/***/ })

/******/    });
/************************************************************************/
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};
/******/    
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        var cachedModule = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId];
/******/        if (cachedModule !== undefined) {
/******/            return cachedModule.exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
/******/            // no module.id needed
/******/            // no module.loaded needed
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/    
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        __webpack_modules__[moduleId](module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/    
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/define property getters */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define getter functions for harmony exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.d = (exports, definition) => {
/******/            for(var key in definition) {
/******/                if(__webpack_require__.o(definition, key) && !__webpack_require__.o(exports, key)) {
/******/                    Object.defineProperty(exports, key, { enumerable: true, get: definition[key] });
/******/                }
/******/            }
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/hasOwnProperty shorthand */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        __webpack_require__.o = (obj, prop) => (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))
/******/    })();
/******/    
/******/    /* webpack/runtime/make namespace object */
/******/    (() => {
/******/        // define __esModule on exports
/******/        __webpack_require__.r = (exports) => {
/******/            if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/                Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/            }
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/        };
/******/    })();
/******/    
/************************************************************************/
/******/    
/******/    // startup
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    // This entry module doesn't tell about it's top-level declarations so it can't be inlined
/******/    var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__(181);
/******/    
/******/    return __webpack_exports__;
/******/ })()
;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

when running `analysis.run_analysis('analysis1', points)` Im getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: angle is not defined`

Comment: In safe mode eval doesn't have access to global variables, so it seems like the issue is either that your build script is putting your code in safe mode, or that it's not putting those variables in the global scope. For a simple personal utility, any kind of build script, especially one that does minification, seems unnecessary.

Comment: In any case, you really need to show the final code. Without that, and without seeing your build script, it's impossible to tell you wht the problem is. Most of us aren't clairvoyant so we would only be guessing.

Comment: The main reason Im using webpack is just to compile multiple files into a single js, but I actually used minification: false and run into the same issue

Comment: may be it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808244/alternative-to-eval-function-due-to-minification

Comment: @jtomasrl - again, show the final transpiled code. you can't expect us to guess what the problem is without the actual code. When you have a scope issue it's important to show the entire code.

Comment: i did uploaded the transpiled code, even though there are some small differences in variables names and stuff i've been moving around

Comment: Webpack isn't putting anything in the global scope. That's your problem. Webpack is way overkill just for concatenating some files. You should write your own build script that simply concats the files into a new file without any transpilation.

Comment: thanks for the hint, so now I moved to grunt in order to just merge all files together, but now the variables created inside the for loop are not accesible when declared using eval(`var ${key} = [${value}];`);